# Why do cached resources might take long to render in the browser?

Tags: javascript, css, caching

I have a strange problem. I'm generating css and js in PHP, the code is correctly cached in the browser but it takes a long time to render as you can see from the image.

[image]

I can confirm that the cache is working as no calls are made to the server ( i have firePHP for that ) and you can see things live here http://www.nwkidsmagazine.com/kids-activities-and-things-to-do/

Has anyone an explanation for this?

EDIT - This is the function that's called to render the css

```
public function render_css() {
    header( 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' );
    header( 'Content-Type: text/css', true, 200 );
    // Aggressive caching to save future requests from the same client.
    $etag = '"' . md5( __FILE__ . $_GET[self::GET_VARIBALE_NAME] ) . '"';
    header( 'ETag: ' . $etag );
    $max_age = 31536000;
    header(
        'Expires: ' .
        gmdate(
            'D, d M Y H:i:s',
            Ai1ec_Time_Utility::current_time() + $max_age
        ) .
        ' GMT'
    );
    header( 'Cache-Control: public, max-age=' . $max_age );
    if (
        empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) ||
        $etag !== stripslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] )
    ) {
        // compress data if possible
        $zlib_output_handler = ini_get( 'zlib.output_handler' );
        if (
            true === extension_loaded( 'zlib' ) &&
            ! in_array( 'ob_gzhandler', ob_list_handlers() ) &&
            ! in_array(
                strtolower( ini_get( 'zlib.output_compression' ) ),
                array( '1', 'on' )
            ) &&
            empty( $zlib_output_handler )
        ) {
            ob_start( 'ob_gzhandler' );
            header( 'Content-Encoding: gzip' );
        } else {
            ob_start();
        }
        $content = $this->get_compiled_css();
        echo $content;
        ob_end_flush();
    } else {
        // Not modified!
        status_header( 304 );
    }
    // We're done!
    ai1ec_stop( 0 );
}
```

and this is for js

```
public function render_js() {
    header( 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' );
    header( 'Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8', true, 200 );
    // Aggressive caching to save future requests from the same client.
    $etag = '"' . md5( __FILE__ . $_GET[self::LOAD_JS_PARAMETER] ) . '"';
    header( 'ETag: ' . $etag );
    $max_age = 31536000;// One Year
    header(
        'Expires: ' .
        gmdate(
            'D, d M Y H:i:s',
            Ai1ec_Time_Utility::current_time() + $max_age
        ) .
        ' GMT'
    );
    header( 'Cache-Control: public, max-age=' . $max_age );
    if (
        empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) ||
        $etag !== stripslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] )
    ) {
        // compress data if possible
        $zlib_output_handler = ini_get( 'zlib.output_handler' );
        if (
            true === extension_loaded( 'zlib' ) &&
            ! in_array( 'ob_gzhandler', ob_list_handlers() ) &&
            ! in_array(
                strtolower( ini_get( 'zlib.output_compression' ) ),
                array( '1', 'on' )
            ) &&
            empty( $zlib_output_handler )
        ) {
            ob_start( 'ob_gzhandler' );
            header( 'Content-Encoding: gzip' );
        } else {
            ob_start();
        }

        $js_path = AI1EC_ADMIN_THEME_JS_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $common_js = '';
        $page_to_load = $_GET[self::LOAD_JS_PARAMETER];

        if ( $_GET[self::IS_BACKEND_PARAMETER] === self::TRUE_PARAM ) {
            $common_js = file_get_contents( $js_path . 'pages/common_backend.js' );
        } else if( $page_to_load === self::EVENT_PAGE_JS ||
            $page_to_load === self::CALENDAR_PAGE_JS || 
            $page_to_load === self::LOAD_ONLY_FRONTEND_SCRIPTS ) {
            if ( $page_to_load === self::LOAD_ONLY_FRONTEND_SCRIPTS &&
                true === self::$frontend_scripts_loaded ) {
                return;
            }
            if ( false === self::$frontend_scripts_loaded ) {
                $common_js = file_get_contents( $js_path . 'pages/common_frontend.js' );
                self::$frontend_scripts_loaded = true;
            }

        }
        // create the config object for require js
        $require_config = $this->create_require_js_config_object();
        // load require
        $require = file_get_contents( $js_path . 'require.js' );

        // get jquery
        $jquery = $this->get_jquery_version_based_on_browser( 
            $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
        );
        // load the script for the page

        $page_js = '';
        if ( $page_to_load !== self::LOAD_ONLY_BACKEND_SCRIPTS &&
             $page_to_load !== self::LOAD_ONLY_FRONTEND_SCRIPTS
        ) {
            $page_js = file_get_contents( $js_path . 'pages/' . $page_to_load );
        }


        $translation = $this->get_frontend_translation_data();
        $permalink = get_permalink( $this->settings->calendar_page_id );

        $translation['calendar_url'] = $permalink;

        $tranlsation_module = $this->create_require_js_module( 
            self::FRONTEND_CONFIG_MODULE, 
            $translation 
        );
        $config = $this->create_require_js_module(
            'ai1ec_config',
            $this->get_translation_data()
        );
        echo $require . $require_config . $tranlsation_module . 
                $config . $jquery . $page_js . $common_js;
        ob_end_flush();
    } else {
        // Not modified!
        status_header( 304 );
    }
    // We're done!
    ai1ec_stop( 0 );
}
```

Comment: [Maybe this will help?](https://www.google.com/search?q=all+in+one+event+calendar&oq=all+in+one+event+&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l2j69i62l2.5050j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=all+in+one+event+calendar+slow&oq=all+in+one+event+calendar+slow&gs_l=serp.3..0.1047.2331.0.2569.5.5.0.0.0.0.99.410.5.5.0.ernk_timecombined...0.0..1.1.20.psy-ab.IGT0T1j0VCw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49967636%2Cd.aWc%2Cpv.xjs.s.en_US.jOYpRJj4zMA.O&fp=892d50b55da110e7&biw=1280&bih=923)

Comment: @MiniRagnarok yes i work for that plugin :D

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti - I would suggest computing the `ETag` from a combination of the *File Name, Last Modified Date, and File Size*. Right now it looks like you are calculating the MD5 hash for the entire file contents every time. Using just those three properties will be an extremely fast operation, and should be sufficient.

Comment: @Josh actually __FILE__ in PHP it's just the filename, i should simply move the Etag check much earlier in WordPress lifecycle, i just wonder why Expires header are not set correctly

Answer (score 3):

To say that no calls are being made to the server is not accurate. **[A response of 304](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5) means that a request was made to the server, but the server indicated the resource had not been modified**, and therefore did not need to re-send the resource.

However, **it still has to wait for the server to respond** with that 304. In my quick testing of the page, there are a couple of resources that take quite a while before the server responds with that 304.

### Findings

In my testing the largest amount of time is spent simply waiting on the server to respond to the initial request.

There are however a couple of resources that will always be re-requested simply because of how the caching headers are set.

For instance, this resource:

`http://www.nwkidsmagazine.com/?ai1ec_render_js=calendar.js&is_backend=false&is_calendar_page=true&ver=1.11.2-pro`

Always sets it's `Expires` header to be the current Date Time stamp. **So the client will always request it from the server.**

It happens to also be the biggest offender, **sometimes taking upwards of 5 seconds** to respond to the initial request.

If this is a dynamic resource, then I would suggest coming up with a simpler and faster mechanism for determining the `ETag`. **Since an ETag SHOULD always take precedence, it really needs to be a fast operation.**

Comment: Some resources are compiled in PHP (our CSS and our JS for example) and so the server might be slow even to respond to a 304 but i see also some static files which are slow

Comment: And one more thing, if i set the caching headers and the link is not changed why do it still call the server?

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti The caching headers are a *suggestion* to the client, but I can still force it to request the resources again by simply hitting F5 in the browser. Doing so essentially sets the `cache-control` header to `max-age=0`

Comment: I added the function i use to generate the CSS, this function is called in a wordpress hook but i could make the etag check earlier than this.

Comment: I also added the function that creates the javascript from the link you mentioned

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti If the content doesn't change between versions, then I would set the `Expires` header to be out into the future. This way you can just let the browser cache the results and until the URL changes, or the `Expires` time elapses, it won't request a new resource. This still leaves you with the unpleasant load times associated with initially pulling down the resource. I think I would spend the majority of my time figuring out how to make that faster. Perhaps pre-computing and caching the results.

Comment: Hi, everything is cached, for js we just serve files and for CSS only the first load is compiled as it's less. I will try to to put things a little earlier in wordpress lifecycle but for javascript that's impossible,
And i thought i was setting the Expires header to be in the future, if you look at the code i pasted it should be set in the future, why does the browser keep requesting it?